# solr pagination and grouping

Tags: solr, lucene

I am using LucidWorks and Solr to implement search in a large and diverse web app which has many different types of pages. The spec calls for a single search results page grouped by page type with pagination of search results in each group.

I can group easily enough with something like this

```
q=[searchterm]&group=true&group.field=[pagetypefield]
```

which returns nicely grouped results.

I can also do:

```
q=[searchterm]&group=true&group.field=[pagetypefield]&group.offset=[x]&group.limit=[y]
```

which will get me y results per group starting at result x

However what i want to be able to do is supply an offset and limit per group because i might want to get results 0-4 for group 1 and results 5-9 for group 2.

The values for `[pagetypefield]` are a list of known values so i can do multiple queries like:

```
q=[searchterm]&group=true&group.query=[pagetypefield]:[value]&group.offset=[x]&group.limit=[y]
```

for each known value of `[pagetypefield]`

or to not use group.offset and in my example get results 0-9 for both groups and just discard the results i don't need.

I don't really like either option but i can't find a way in the documentation to specify offset and limit on a per group basis.

Any advice would be most appreciated.

Comment: If someone can help by confirming what I want to do can't be done i would accept that as an answer so that at least i don't waste time pursuing a dead end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have confirmation from LucinWorks that what i want to do is not possible and they recommended the multiple search solution as the first search will be chached so subsequent searches will be really fast.

What I think I'm going to end up doing is to group the search results taking first n results for each group, then use ajax to paginate each group.

Comment: Hey, how did you end up implementing pagination. I've a use case, in which I'm using group search and I need a total of 20 results, top 3 results from one group(can have a lower score), and other 17 based on the scores.